Java for loop vs kotlin for loop
How to modify the size of a list while iterating in Kotlin for loop?
Here is a sample Java for loop
for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
    if (someCondition()) {
        list.remove(j);
    }
}

Here is equivalent Kotlin code
for (j in 0 ..  list.size) {
    if (someCondition()) {
        list.removeAt(j)
    }
}

In Java, when the list is modified by remove, the size is updated and IndexOutofBoundException is not thrown
But in Kotlin, size gets updated, but the kotlin style of for loop does not consider the new size and continues to run above it and causes IndexOutOfBoundException
Is there a Kotlin alternative to this?

Do you realize your java version skips elements? If you remove element 3, then the index will be 4 on the next loop, but the fourth element will now be at index 3.

You could try using a MutableIterator your java code should also use an iterator.

Like matt said, such a loop is rarely desirable, regardless of the language. Do you understand what you are doing?

I understand, It was just an old codebase auto converted to kotlin causing error, i have solved it, but was wondering why did kotlin style of for loop is not considering the new size anyways

I do not know Kotlin, but I assume that for (j in ...) is more like enhanced fors in Java for (int j : ...) -- "why did kotlin style of for loop is not considering the new size" - probably because 0 ..  list.size represent the set of numbers in that range, calculated once, and not some kind of dynamic range (not kind of lambda?)

Wow, I think this is the first time I see so many answers to a question, each of them looking at the question from a different angle and all of them providing valuable information :+1:

Iterating over a list while mutating it is a very tricky case and it is easy to do it wrong. Using indexes is error-prone in this case. Instead, we can use a mutable iterator:
fun main() {
    val list = (0..10).toMutableList()

    val iter = list.listIterator()
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        val item = iter.next()
        println(item) // 0, 1, 2, 3, ...

        if (item % 2 == 0) {
            iter.remove()
        }
    }

    println(list) // [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
}

Iterator handles indexes automatically for us, so the code is cleaner and more error-proof.
Answering your question directly: it still uses the old size(), because during the loop initialization we create the range 0 ..  list.size, then we iterate over it. We don't create a new range with each iteration.

I believe I can use list.removeAll {it%2==0}? It does work the same way right

That code will work correctly, when the previous versions didn't.

This is also how this should be done in Java.

Mutable iterators, such as suggested by @broot, are a clean way to remove elements on the fly (mutating a collection while iterating most often has unwanted side effects).
Or one could use the built-in removeIf functionality of mutable lists, which accepts a predicate:
Kotlin:
val l = mutableListOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
l.removeIf { (it % 2) == 0 }
l.forEach { println(it) }

Java:
var l = new ArrayList<>(List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
l.removeIf(it -> (it % 2) == 0);
l.forEach(System.out::println);


Not quite a direct translation, but one approach you might consider is to create a new list, instead of mutating the existing one.  That's much safer, and usually much simpler and easier to read too.
For example:
list = list.filterNot{ someCondition() }

…if list is a mutable reference, or:
val filteredList = list.filterNot{ someCondition() }

(Or you could invert the condition and remove the Not.)
That avoids all the issues around modifying during iteration, or keeping track of the indices.  (It also avoids some thread-safety issues, though not all.  And it works for immutable lists too.)
As for performance, it takes a little more memory for the duplicate list, though probably for only a very short time; but it's likely to be quicker if two or more elements are being removed (potentially a lot quicker for many — linear instead of quadratic — depending on the List implementation).  So it's likely to be a win overall.

Did you intend to call the same function for both mutable and immutable lists?

@k314159 Yes: I was referring to mutable or immutable references — i.e. to whether list was defined as var list that could be reassigned to the new list (my first case), or val list that couldn't (my second).  In both cases, the existing list isn't modified, so could be read-only.

Kotlin for loops are all iterator based. When you do for (j in 0 ..  list.size), you are just iterating over the IntRange of 0..list.size. The for loop gets an Iterator from the IntRange and repeatedly calls hasNext and next on that iterator.
The iterator of an IntRange obviously does not know about the size of the list changing.
(Also note that the correct range is 0 until list.size - the inclusive 0..list.size will be out of bounds even without removing any elements)
You could use a while loop, which is condition-based.
var i = 0
while (i < list.size) {
    // ...
    i++
}

As a proof of concept, you can write an iterator around a MutableList, and compare the current index against list.size in hasNext, which is called for each iteration.
fun <T> MutableList<T>.dynamicIndices(): Iterable<Int> = object: Iterable<Int> {
    override fun iterator(): Iterator<Int> = DynamicListSizeIterator(this@dynamicIndices)
}

class DynamicListSizeIterator<T>(val list: MutableList<T>) : Iterator<Int> {
    var index = 0
    override fun hasNext() = index < list.size
    override fun next(): Int = index++
}

// example usage:
for (i in list.dynamicIndices()) {
    if (Random.nextBoolean()) {
        list.removeAt(i)
    }
}

In practice though, you should definitely remove elements using the iterator itself, as in broot's answer It is much easier to reason about that.

It might be worth pointing out that although for (j in 0..<list.size) conceptually uses the range's hasNext() and next() functions, for simple integer ranges the implementation optimizes that. Otherwise, some developers might be put off learning Kotlin by erroneously thinking Kotlin for loops are not as efficient as Java for loops.

In Java and Kotlin, you may get ConcurrentModificationException while attempting to change the elements and iterating over them. Also, as @matt pointed out in one of the comments that, your logic will skip elements.
This is fairly easy to achieve using Kotlin's removeAll() and Java's removeIf(). But another naive way that I found useful is to flag the elements that you want to remove and then maybe run through the collection again to remove the flagged items (or put the un-flagged items together).
